# Firebase Storage, putString error: not a multiple of the 262144 byte chunk granularity

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to use `.putString()` to upload a base64 image to Firebase storage, opposed to converting the base64 into a blob then uploading it.

I'm receiving this error:

```
code: "storage/unknown"
message: "Firebase Storage: An unknown error occurred, please check the error payload for server response."
name: "FirebaseError"
serverResponse: "The client sent 3127083 bytes, which is not a multiple of the 262144 byte chunk granularity."
```

The data being sent is a relatively small image: (890, 1334)

```
var uploadTask = firebase.storage().ref('test_photos').child('test.jpeg').putString('data:image/jpeg;base64,'+base64, 'data_url');
```

Am I to believe that the maximum size of a Base64 string can only be 256Kb? That's pretty small.

Comment: The message says that it has to be a *multiple* of 256KB. I'm not sure why that is, but it's definitely not limited to at most 256KB.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen How would I manage to pad the data out to 512KB? Considering this is a Base64 image returned from a OpenGL library in react-native. Blob & Buffer aren't support in react-native without polyfills. Is there any type of padding I can use? The docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files do not say anything about 256Kb blocks, nor do the examples have 256Kb worth of data.

Comment: I should also add that when no error is returned and I get a link: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/qualify-college-dating.appspot.com/o/test_photos%2Ftest_image1.jpeg?alt=media&token=0012bf55-cef8-4e1c-9270-6ece0bad1d6f  The image uploaded is 0 bytes

Comment: Getting the same error here. Any news about that?